# Как заставить врага ходить вверх на unity2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть враг и персонаж. По [Видеоролику](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVmEtfQwQW4) сделал его движение по x, но по y не получилось, помогите сделать движение по y.

Вот мой код:

```
    private Rigidbody2D phys;
    public Transform player;

    public float speed;
    public int DistanceToAgr;
    void Start()
    {
        phys = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);
        if (distToPlayer < DistanceToAgr)
        {
            if (player.position.x < transform.position.x) //лево
            {
                phys.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
            }
            else if (player.position.x > transform.position.x) //право
            {
                phys.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
            }
            //Пробовал по y, но не получилось
            //else if (player.position.y < transform.position.y) 
            //{
                //phys.velocity = new Vector2(0, -speed);
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            phys.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видео не смотрел, но, судя по коду, не советую смотреть другие видео от этого автора, если он изобретает велосипеды для того, что можно сделать в 2 строки.

Итак.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))] // Чтобы добавлялся компонент, если его нет но объекте
public class TargetFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _target; // [SerializeField] для отображения private полей в инспекторе

    [SerializeField] private float _speed;
    [SerializeField] private float _agressionDistance;

    [SerializeField] private float _followDistance;

    private Rigidbody2D _rb;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Follow(_target);
    }

    private void Follow(Transform target)
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > _agressionDistance) return; // Если дистанция до таргета больше, чем дистанция агрессии, то ничего не делаем
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < _followDistance) return; // Если дистанция до таргета меньше, чем дистанция следования, то ничего не делаем

        var direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        _rb.velocity = direction * _speed;
    }
}
```

Думаю, что код до метода `Follow` объяснять не нужно, там достаточно комментариев и все примитивно.

`var direction...` здесь, посредством вычитания векторов, мы определяем направление в сторону таргета. Отнимая от вектора позиции таргета вектор нашей позиции, мы получаем вектор, который смотрит в направлении таргета. Далее мы его нормализуем, чтобы от длины вектора не зависела скорость объекта. И далее мы берем это направление, умножаем на желаемую скорость и присваиваем эту скорость объекту.

И ВСЕ. Никаких if else if else if else.

Если нужна будет производительность, то вместо `(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position)` можно использовать `(target.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude`, который возвращает `КВАДРАТ` дистанции.

И модификатор доступа private не просто так придумали. public поля и св-ва должны быть очень редкими и то, желательно readonly, чтобы нельзя было состояние объекта изменять как захочется и кому захочется. Более подробно про инкапсуляцию можно найти в интернете.

Comment: Ваш код работает, спасибо! Однако Позиция таргета не обновляется, поэтому враги идут в одну точку. Как можно её обновлять?

Comment: В каком смысле позиция таргета не обновляется? Если поле _target не пустое, то за этим таргетом они и будут следовать, что-то изменяли в коде? Поля agressiondistance и followdistance надо настраивать под свои нужды. Первое отвечает за дистанцию, на которой начинается преследование, второе за дистанцию, на которой они будут следовать от таргета.

Comment: С параметрами я уже разобрался, но всё же это мне не помогло. Враг не преследует игрока, проверил через `Debug.Log(target.position)` - не меняется. НО, если во время игры в инспекторе вновь поставить объект с игроков в переменную _target, то он будет следовать за игроком.

Comment: То есть, изначально таргет в инспекторе установлен, но после запуска сцены, он оттуда пропадает?

Comment: Нет, он остаётся там. После того, как я запустил сцену, он остаётся там и враг идёт в точку где БЫЛ игрок, а если опять кинуть таргет в инспектор, то он следует за игроком

Comment: Код мой как-либо изменяли?

Comment: Только название скрипта, больше ничего

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134519/discussion-between-kotlk-and-).